# d3.js sankey link color

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am looking for making the link color same as node fill color in d3 sankey charts.

I am using following function to get the node color

```
function getNodeColor(d){
          console.log(d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2));
          return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2);
}
```

Following is my code for painting the text color of the links

```
// add in the title for the nodes
    node.append("text")
        .attr("x", -6)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", null)
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
        .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .style("stroke", getNodeColor);
```

Above works perfectly fine and the text displays the node text with the node color.
Same is not true when I try to change the stroke value in link definition by same way :

```
 var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
        .style("stroke", getNodeColor)
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });
```

I am new to d3 sankey and follow http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c9b90689c1438f57d649

Help appreciated...

Bottomline : I am looking for making the link/chord colors of sankey chart same as that of rect fill color...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code to use the source node color for the links in your graph. You could also use `target.color` if you prefer to use the target node color.

```
svg.selectAll(".link")
  .style('stroke', function(d){
    return d.source.color;
  })
```

This code would need to be placed after the code which sets the node colors.

Comment: managed to achieve the gradient with help of http://jsfiddle.net/CeAZQ/3/, thanks!